# Hide icon of installed app in android

Tags: android, package-managers

i cant hide the Installed app in android .. i used below code..

disableDrawerIcon("com.androglobe.androrec");

```
public void disableDrawerIcon(String component) {
    try {
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
        ComponentName componentName = null;
        for (ResolveInfo temp : appList) {  

            if (temp.activityInfo.packageName.equals(component)) {

                componentName = new ComponentName(component,
                        temp.activityInfo.name);

                Log.v(TAG, ""+temp.activityInfo.name);
            }

        }

        if (componentName != null) {


        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        Log.v(TAG, "Icon disabled");

        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "ERROR");
    }
    }
```

So please help me....
thanks in advance...

Comment: be more  specific about what you need..

Comment: I want to hide the other installed application icon from main menu in android...

Comment: Hi @sharath. Did you find any solution to hide installed application without rooted android device? If you find any solution then please upload the sample. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lawrence sorry dude still i din't find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have a launcher icon on your app just don't put the "LAUNCHER" category in any activity of the "AndroidManifest.xml" file. The category looks like this:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: I want to hide the other installed app... not mien app

Comment: Perfect Perfect Perfect... :)
i wanted this thing... this simple thing was not coming to my mind..thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

From your manifest for all activities.

Comment: You mean an installed 3rd party app that is not your own?

Comment: @Tom it will hide icon but i want to open that apps also from another apps then how can start that app?